# Bootstrap 3.0 grids - how to transpose them in vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap grids, and was searching for a fast / non-invasive way for showing in vertical some elements using a grid.

For example, if usually I'd obtain (i.e using col-md-3):

```
A B C D 
E F G H
I L M N
O P Q R
```

in my version I would have "transposed" version:

```
A E I O
B F L P
C G M Q
D H N R
```

IS that just server-side problem, or there is a way for doing that with grids CSS and/or javascript?

S

Comment: you need to go for BootstrapV4

Comment: No css can do that for you. I don't see how Bootstrapv4 would help. This is a jQuery/javascript problem. Or even AngularJS.

Comment: I think the simplest solution is server side.  inverting the loop for echoing/rendering ...not css and not of course bootstrap..

Comment: I know this coud sound weird, but is strictly request by customer, for my bad luck. Need to use bootstrap 3, can't switch to 4 in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In your original example it looks like you are opening a `ul` tag and then giving each `li` a class of `col-md-3`.

What you could do to achieve the desired result is open up 4 `ul` tags instead (one for each column) and give each a class of `col-md-3`.  Then the `li` tags inside these `ul` tags will not need any class on them.

Here is what that code would look like:

```
<ul class="col-md-3">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-md-3">
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
    <li>H</li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-md-3">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>M</li>
    <li>N</li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-md-3">
    <li>O</li>
    <li>P</li>
    <li>Q</li>
    <li>R</li>
</ul>
```

This may not be exactly how you were looking to accomplish this, but this will achieve the desired result.  I hope this helps!

Comment: this sounds good, seems ok for what I needed - and don't need resort / change server side code. Thanks!